# Can I include/import a single function from a library in C++

Tags: c++, linker, g++, binutils

I only need to use the `iequals` case-insensitive string comparison function from the BOOST library.

I am using `#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>` to import it.

Is there any way that I could only import the `iequals` function by itself?

The reason I even care (I am really just curious.) is because the compiled DLL is about 230kB if I don't `#include` it and about 1.1MB if I do.  It doesn't really make much difference in this particular case how large the file is, but it seems like there is a lot of stuff that gets imported and never used.  What if the library was a few GB and I only needed one of the functions?  Then it would become an issue, I imagine.

I am admittedly naive when it comes to just about anything cpp-related, but I feel like it isn't very efficient to include some 750kB of code when probably 90% of it isn't used.  It could be that the `iequals` function uses all of that 750kB, I have no idea.

Then again, if the `iequals` function includes many of the same libraries, the file would still be just as large.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

EDIT:

Thanks for the responses.  I am doing my best to understand them.

I am a chemical engineer who is rewriting a bunch of horribly slow and poorly optimized VBA macros into a C++ DLL.  So far the results have been outstanding and everything functions correctly.  I just don't see the need for the extra file size if I only need to do a single type of comparison between two strings.

An example of the comparison I need to do is as follows:

```
if (SomeBSTR == "SomeTextHere") {
    // do stuff
}
```

or more exactly:

```
if (Gas == "Methane"    or
    Gas == "CH4"        or
    Gas == "C1")        return 1;

if (Gas == "Ethane"     or
    Gas == "C2H6"       or
    Gas == "C2")        return 2;
```

If this is the ONLY type of comparison that I have to do, can I do it in a more simple way than:

```
int wStrCmp(const BSTR Str1, const wstring Str2) {

    wstring wStr1(Str1, SysStringLen(Str1));

    return boost::iequals(Str1, Str2);
}
```

which is called via:

```
if (wStrCmp(Gas, L"Methane")      or
    wStrCmp(Gas, L"CH4")          or
    wStrCmp(Gas, L"C1"))          return 1;
```

Those last 2 blocks are practically pasted from my code.

Thanks again, guys.

Comment: Have you considered using [`strcasecmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp) (POSIX) or [`_stricmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (Windows) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

believe me you already just include `boost::algorithm::iequals` but it use `boost::range` and `std::locale` that possibly you don't use them in other places of your code, so this make your code a lot bigger, so I guess for your case there is no other way to do that unless you use some non-standard function like `stricmp` or `strcasecmp`.

If you want to compare wide strings on Windows(for example `BSTR`) you can use `_wcsicmp` from CRT or `lstrcmpiW` from Windows runtime(declared in `Kernel32.lib` that possibly you already linked with it).

Comment: Perhaps there is a better what to do what I am trying to do with the comparison.  I need to take a BSTR (from Excel) and compare it with another string (currently using `L"text"` as the other string), independent of case.

The easiest way that I have found to compare the BSTR and the other string is to use the `L"text` for the other string and `boost/algorithm/string.hpp` header.

I just wish it didnt make the file size quadruple.

Comment: @Dr3vvn45ty not that you haven't already looked, but, would [lstrcmpiw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647489(v=vs.85).aspx) do what you're looking for? perhaps not, but worth at least a look since it is Windows, after all. If not that, then perhaps [CompareString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317759(v=vs.85).aspx) may be a better option for you. Just ideas.

Comment: @WhozCraig
Maybe if I could reduce the BSTR to a LPCTSTR.  I will look into that.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dr3vvn45ty A BSTR, unless specifically crafted to include imbedded null-chars, is a wide-char string already. IOW, you can use your BSTR from Excel as one of the parameters to the wide-char version of lstrcmpi(), (which is the **lstrcmpiw()** (note the 'w') I mentioned earlier). If you need more flexibility (locales and such) CompareString() may be better suited for you. But at least under Windows you most-definitely do NOT have to suck in boost lib just to compare two wide-strings case-insensitive. The OS already has native support for it.

Comment: Oh, and +1 for a nice explanation for why bringing in something that seems innocently small can pull more than you first expected from boost. gj, BB.